SSRS Multi-Column Reporting in Sub-Report Not Rendering in PDF
I have a functional multi-column SSRS report that when saved to PDF displays correctly.  However, when used as a sub-report and saved to PDF it does not display correctly.
Steps (Stand alone report):

Created multi-column report to display student transcripts.
Executed report and saved as PDF.
Opened PDF and report renders as expected.


Steps (As sub-report):

Created parent report to include student transcripts.
Executed report and saved as PDF.
Opened PDF and report renders with only a single column.


I didn't find any limitations in Microsoft's documentation regarding the use of a multi-column report as a sub-report, and saving it as a PDF. Essentially, I expected the format of the PDF files to be identical where this report is used, regardless if it's executed on its own or as part of another report.  Is there a solution for this type of situation?
Thanks.

I don't know if this if this is a limitation of these type of reports as there are several limitations with multi-column layouts, but that aside, have you ensured there is enough space in the sub report container to accommodate two columns? Try, as a test, making the subreport column much narrower and see if that makes a difference, at least you could rule that option out.

Alan, great suggestion but resizing the columns in the sub-report didn't work.
